# HBase: How to write custom skip filter after 0.96.0?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hbase

I am new to HBase.  I want to make a custom fuzzy filter in HBase but have been having great difficulty finding any resources to explain the proper way to do so in java. The only examples I've found seems to use a version of HBase in which FilterBase supplies different functions, as do all source codes for existing filters which I can find. (0.94.0 I think)

More specifically, I found [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client/0.98.1-hadoop2/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FuzzyRowFilter.java?av=f) code for FuzzyRowFilter which I would like to slightly modify.  However, as seen [here](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterBase.html), functions like *filterKeyValue*, *write*, and *readFiles* are not part of FilterBase anymore?  If I paste said FuzzyRowFilter code into my Eclipse project, I get notices that those three functions aren't being inherited.

Could someone please explain how one is supposed to make a custom row-skipping filter in the current HBase? What is the flow of the code? I'm using 0.96.0 (but the FilterBase that's part of it seems to match the linked 0.99.0 documentation)

EDIT:

Based on [this blog post](http://bigdataexplorer.wordpress.com/2013/10/29/hbase-0-96-0-release-protobufs-as-wire-format), I take it that write and readFiles from 0.94 are simply not needed in 0.96, and after a lot of digging I found that I instead need to use "parseFrom" and "toByteArray". Using these methods prevents any errors from coming, but I still don't understand how to properly use them, as my filter doesn't seem to ever begin. (as far as I can tell, only toByteArray is getting called, and never parseFrom)

I'm guessing there's something wrong with my understanding of the filter+protobuf structure, so the original question remains.